# Ajax code dose not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Sorry for my english...

why this ajax code dosen't work properly ?

when I call the POST variable in the page that i send for him the info, its show me that the POST variable is not exist...

Can anybody explain why it is happening ?

*part of the ajax code:*

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",url,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.send("info="+str+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2);
return false;
```

Comment: #Idoroni, POST is an HTTP method, not a variable, could you please clarify your question, may be with more code?

Comment: how do you access the POST-variables in send.php and what are the values of `str`, `info_1` and `info_2`

Comment: if you provide the full block of code, we'll be able to help you to find the issue, otherwise we can't guess the other code part !

Comment: @CodyDmd the web dont let me write so long code. its tell me that i need write more explanation for the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some headers must be included for POST request:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Edit :

My script use a variable called 'params'. So add a var at the beginning of your script and put in it the content of your request :

```
var params = "info="+str+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2;
```

And replace in the call of xhr.send "info="+str+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2; by params:

```
xhr.send(params);
```

Here is the final script:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "info="+str+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2;
xhr.open("POST",url,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.send(params);
return false;
```

Comment: where i need to put this?

Comment: Before you call xhr.send() ;)

Comment: thaks for trying help me! :) but now the code isnt work at all... befor that it was load the send.php page and show me that the POST not exist. now its not load it at all... :/

Comment: did you have any idea why?

Comment: I didn't have finish ;) Have a look now